# add asteriks to correct answers, 2D arrays

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

So this program is supposed to read and count correct answers for each student as well as put up a table of all the questions answered. My issue is there is supposed to be an asteriks next to a correct answer on the 2nd table. It's the only part I'm getting wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
char ch;

string answers, id, responses;
int numstudents = 0, i, j, numcorrect, chart[20][5] = { 0 };


ifstream ftests, fans;
ofstream fout;

ftests.open("Tests.dat");
fans.open("answers.dat");
fout.open("table.out");

fans >> answers;

fout << setw(11) << "student-id" << setw(19) << "number correct" << endl << endl;

ftests >> id >> responses;

while (!ftests.eof())
{
    numstudents++;
    numcorrect = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (responses[i] == answers[i])
        {
            numcorrect++;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {

            if (responses[i] == (char)('A' + j))
            {
                chart[i][j]++;

            }


        }

    }

    fout << setw(11) << id << setw(19) << numcorrect << endl;

    ftests >> id >> responses;

}

fout << endl << endl << endl;

fout << "number of students taking exam = " << numstudents << endl << endl; 

fout << setw(8) << "question" << setw(5) << "A" << setw(5) << "B" << setw(5) << "C" << setw(5) << "D" << setw(5) << "E" << endl;

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    fout << setw(2) << i + 1  << " " << setw(10);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        fout << chart[i][j];

        if (responses[i] == i)//I BELIEVE THE PROBLEM LIES HERE!!!
        {
            fout << "*" << setw(4);
        }
        else
        {
            fout << " " << setw(4);

        }
    }
    fout << endl;
}

}
```

The tables looks like this:

```
 student-id     number correct

430-52-6192                 13
112-81-5225                 19
120-49-5322                 12
456-65-3211                  2
990-45-0978                  4
324-98-5445                  6
112-34-3443                 12
435-56-8790                 18
452-23-5675                  6
776-45-5454                  7
567-71-9909                  6
345-54-7834                  9
555-12-2341                 18
568-09-0096                 20
664-61-0987                 10
612-45-7687                  5
567-23-1125                  3
561-43-6781                  6
498-12-4321                  3
479-01-4867                  4
489-90-0999                 17
456-09-1111                 19
561-66-6657                  3



number of students taking exam = 23

question    A    B    C    D    E
 1          5    1   13    3    1 
 2          4    7    1    7    4 
 3          2    3    2    2   14 
 4          2    1    3   13    4 
 5          2    8    1    4    8 
 6          5    1    3    3   11 
 7          5    7    0    4    7 
 8         11    4    0    3    5 
 9          3    2    1    2   15 
10          0    1   12    3    7 
11          6    2    4   10    1 
12          2    2    4    9    6 
13          9    4    0    6    4 
14          4    2    2    2   13 
15          3    3    1    1   15 
16          1    8    4    3    7 
17          6    3    1    7    6 
18          4    1    2    5   11 
19          0    1    1   10   11 
20          2    0    1    1   19
```

Where as table 2 should look like this:

```
question    A    B    C    D    E
 1          5    1   13*   3    1 
 2          4    7*   1    7    4 
 3          2    3    2    2   14* 
 4          2    1    3   13*   4 
 5          2    8*   1    4    8 
 6          5    1    3    3   11*
 7          5    7*   0    4    7 
 8         11*   4    0    3    5 
 9          3    2    1    2   15*
10          0    1   12*   3    7 
11          6    2    4   10*   1 
12          2    2    4    9*   6 
13          9*   4    0    6    4 
14          4    2    2    2   13*
15          3    3    1    1   15*
16          1    8*   4    3    7 
17          6    3    1    7*   6 
18          4    1    2    5   11*
19          0    1    1   10*  11 
20          2    0    1    1   19*
```

I hope I am being clear enough and any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `i`? Isn't it just your looping variable? Shouldn't it be `answers[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the line "if (responses[i] == i)" would cause a compile error.  This is comparing a string data type to an int.  Based on your earlier lines of code I would think "if (responses[i] == answers[i])" is a better choice.  I am interpreting the meaning of each variable based on context and I may be wrong.  But it seems that answers[] is a list of the correct answers and this comparison is used to count the number of correct answers.  If my interpretation of the variables is wrong then I would suggest defining a variable that allows for this comparison.

Comment: Hmm except answers is declared as `string answers` so it won't be a list...there's more wrong with his program (see how he only reads one word from the answers file). There's a lot more to fix here that you haven't addressed.

Comment: Perhaps you're right but there isn't any info provided in the input file format.  First things first, the line of code highlighted by the author needs to be addressed and it is not correct based on the author's intent.  Given an input file format, e.g. one student per line, or all answers in a single line, then we can address the other items you mention.

Comment: Believe it or not all I had to do was change the part I believed to be wrong. Changed to something similar to.      If(responses[i]==(char)’A’+j) I know it’s not the most efficient way to compile it, but I’m still just starting out. It worked literally 10 min after posting this. My professor told me there was a better way to do it so I’ll be finding out exactly what/how tomorrow. Appreciate all of the constructive criticism!